# mapviz won't show map on real robot

Tags: ros2

I've installed mapviz from binary on ros2 iron following [this](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html) tutorial for navigation stack. Everything works as expected on that demo. I can launch mapviz and the map shows up. I can change lat/lon definition on the world file to the coordinates of my GPS and mapviz shows my location.

Now I want to use mapviz with my own robot. So I run my own robot_localization dual ekf and navsat node but mapviz wont show the map. After a few warnings and some errors the map is not loaded:

```
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.310865913] [mapviz]: Target frame selected: map
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.312678528] [mapviz]: creating: mapviz_plugins/tile_map
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.329849517] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from 'wgs84' to 'map'. If 'map' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970237.329914933] [mapviz]: Error: No transform between wgs84 and map
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.329969518] [mapviz]: Reorder displays
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.334444731] [mapviz]: creating: mapviz_plugins/point_click_publisher
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.410617852] [mapviz]: Publishing points to topic: clicked_point
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.415078459] [mapviz]: Ready.
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.424242578] [mapviz]: Reorder displays
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.424357422] [mapviz]: Publishing points to topic: clicked_point
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.429709922] [mapviz]: creating: mapviz_plugins/tf_frame
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.437347095] [mapviz]: Reorder displays
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.437629616] [mapviz]: Waiting for transform.
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.437667247] [mapviz]: Setting target frame to to base_link
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.438090888] [mapviz]: creating: mapviz_plugins/navsat
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.442910620] [mapviz]: Reorder displays
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.443256920] [mapviz]: No messages received.
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.447384441] [mapviz]: Subscribing to /fix
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.492977834] [mapviz]: OK
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.496088904] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.496183211] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.608824028] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.644285358] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970237.765964087] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.768162238] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Failed to get tf transform ('base_link' to 'map').  Both frames exist in tf.
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970237.772587022] [mapviz]: NETWORK ERROR: Protocol "" is unknown
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.773754987] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.773901773] [mapviz]: OK
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970237.962370595] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.962675939] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Failed to get tf transform ('base_link' to 'map').  Both frames exist in tf.
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.964708782] [mapviz]: API Key Set.
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970237.966012186] [mapviz]: OK
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970237.966397494] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970238.125979271] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970238.126305363] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Failed to get tf transform ('base_link' to 'map').  Both frames exist in tf.
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970238.127018689] [mapviz]: NETWORK ERROR: Protocol "" is unknown
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970238.130293670] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970238.248568235] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970238.248914090] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: Failed to get tf transform ('base_link' to 'map').  Both frames exist in tf.
[mapviz-1] [WARN] [1705970238.252063924] [mapviz]: [transform_manager]: No transformer from '' to 'tf'. If '' is a /tf frame, it may not have been broadcast recently.
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970238.260254833] [mapviz]: NETWORK ERROR: Protocol "" is unknown
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705970238.262219333] [mapviz]: OK
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970238.294023996] [mapviz]: NETWORK ERROR: Protocol "" is unknown
[mapviz-1] [ERROR] [1705970238.303270983] [mapviz]: NETWORK ERROR: Protocol "" is unknown
```

I'm not sure why using nav2 demo it's working ok, but with my robot doesn't. On mapviz GUI I get green OK on each panles and I get the arrow (representing my robot) with a little bit of jumping (like I see on rviz), but the map is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had similar issues but on demo simulation ( I checked you were able to run the demo without errors).

In my case I needed to run the launch files separately in the following order to make the map appears on mapviz:

- Commented out mapviz and robot localization (dual_ekf...launch) launch files from the main launch file (navigation2 navigator)
- Launched at first mapviz launch file and used bing key
- Launched later robot localization launch file
- Finally I have launched the navigation launch file (with robot model, gazebo etc).

For some synchronization reason, it worked. But I still did not try on a real robot (perhaps it can be only TF error).

Comment: are you using ros2 iron? Following the tutorial (https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html) I get it working on Iron

Comment: Yes I am also using Iron! I am happy that it worked!